# Starting an elevated command prompt from a folder's context menu in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, command-line, context-menu, elevation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Easiest way to get right-click “Open command window here” with admin priveleges in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/135501/easiest-way-to-get-right-click-open-command-window-here-with-admin-priveleges-i)

Windows 7 will display an 'Open command prompt here' context menu item if you hold the shift key down while right clicking on a folder (in Windows Explorer). I have read a couple of pages on the web which state that holding Ctrl+Shift down while clicking the 'Open command prompt here' menu item will start the command prompt with elevated privileges. This does not work on my 64-bit Windows 7 machine. I can start other programs from the task bar with elevated privileges by holding down Ctrl+Shift while clicking on the icon.

Did this feature exist in a beta version of Windows 7 and has been removed now or is there something I am missing?

Comment: Related: [Easiest way to get right-click "Open command window here" with admin privileges in Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/135501/easiest-way-to-get-right-click-open-command-window-here-with-admin-priveleges-i)