# How to achieve "Open cmd.exe here" in Windows context menu to "Run as Administrator"?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, runas

I found a way how to add a context menu, when I right click in a Windows explorer, to open command line in a **current directory**.

It is sufficient to create two Windows registry entries:

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\CommandPrompt` e.g. with value `"Open CMD here..."`
and
`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\CommandPrompt\command` with value 
`"cmd.exe /k cd /d %1"`

or simple creating a file *cmd.reg* and executing it:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\CommandPrompt]
@="Open CMD here..."

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\CommandPrompt\command]
@="cmd.exe /k cd /d %1"
```

But how can I achieve the **same thing**, which will force *cmd.exe* to **"Run as Administrator"**?

Comment: This question should be on SuperUser.

Comment: Dupe: [Easiest way to get right-click "Open command window here" with admin priveleges in Windows 7](http://superuser.com/q/135501)

Comment: Just [add this code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12264592/1768141) to your batch script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is however more possible by "hacking" the registry, like losing the need to push shift.. just a right click is enough imo.. and why not have two seperate clear entries ? :-)

Each key with runas is an run as admin-key basically in combination with "HasLUAShield"="" before specifying the same command as when having no elevated rights.

The tweak below will make everything crystal clear.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
; OLDSKOOL-TWEAK : Open command prompt on drives, directories
; version rightclick (no shift needed) :
; for standard "Open command window here"
; and added : "Open command windows here (Admin)"
;
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cmd]
@="@shell32.dll,-8506"
"Extended"=-
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cmd\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runas]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runas]
@="Open command window here (Admin)"
"HasLUAShield"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runas\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\cmd]
@="@shell32.dll,-8506"
"Extended"=-
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\cmd\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\runas]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\runas]
@="Open command window here (Admin)"
"HasLUAShield"="

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\runas\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\cmd]
@="@shell32.dll,-8506"
"Extended"=-
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\cmd\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\runas]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\runas]
@="Open command window here (Admin)"
"HasLUAShield"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\runas\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to hack your registry. Just use shift right click. Also, I believe that menu gives you a command prompt as admin option. If not, just create a registry for a cmd shortcut that starts in system32. That's basically the admin command prompt

Comment: Thanks for your hint, but it does not solve my need to be able to run this "As administrator"

Comment: @ethcz Sorry I didn't make it very clear I actually did. You need to make a shortcut for cmd.exe that starts in System32. After that create a registry in your context menu for the shortcut